# Installing Windows 8.1 works but not Windows 7

Tags: windows-7

Got a new build all ready. Core i7 6700K with stock clock on an Asrock Z170 EXTREME7+ motherboard and (4x16) 64 GB of DDR4-2800 PC4-22400 RAM

When I insert a Windows 7 Installation disk it freezes at the Languange Option. When I insert Windows 8.1 disk everything goes smoothly. What could be the issue here? What can I do to make windows 7 install successfully.

Comment: Just to avoid the obvious: Does your windows 7 DVD work in another computer or does it also freeze there?

Comment: Does 4 x 32 GB really equal 64 GB? Also, are you booting in UEFI mode or BIOS?

Answer (score 0):

Boy did I really write 4 x 32 GB of RAM... I meant 4 x 16 GB. I found the solution to this question. http://www.asrock.com/microsite/Win7Install/

> If you are installing Windows 7 with an optical disc drive and USB keyboard or mouse, please enable the "PS/2 Simulator" option in UEFI SETUP UTILITY > Advanced > USB Configuration.

Comment: I edited in what I expect was the solution. If that is the wrong text, please edit it to be the correct text. It is a good idea to include the actual solution in your answer rather than a link, as the link could change in the future. Please see [DenverCoder9](https://xkcd.com/979/).

Comment: Could you expand the answer here? Then we can still read it after the link dies.

Comment: @BramMooij - The answer should be deleted, since the author was replying, since they have multiple accounts.  To clarify while the emulation mode might still need to be enabled, I have my doubts, that alone will solve the problem.

Comment: @ Ramhound, I do not understand why the answer should be deleted if it was answered by the author. Isn't it perfectly legitimate to answer your own question?

Comment: @BramMooij - At first glance I thought the user had created two users accounts, since half of this answer, is a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Your [Asrock Z170 EXTREME7+ motherboard](http://www.asrock.com/mb/Intel/Z170%20Extreme7+/) is build around a chipset which no longer supports [EHCI](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/io/universal-serial-bus/ehci-specification.html).

The Enhanced Host Controller Interface (EHCI) specification describes the register-level interface for a host controller for the **Universal Serial Bus (USB) Revision 2.0.**

In other words, you can install windows 7 perfectly fine using the classical way of a DVDROM, a PS2 keyboard and a PS/2 mouse.

However if you try to use a USB based device then you will either need to load drivers (the famous <kbd>F6</kbd> and insert a floppy<sup>*</sup>). This is not different from any other installation with windows, but we tend to get used to the current generation of windows OS's to have most drivers already build in. In your case you have a very modern motherboard which has done away with old backward compatabi,ity and it needs a modern driver. So you have to supply that driver.

[Edit]
Or install an USB1 or USB2 plugin card with supported drivers on the win7 iso.

---

<sup>*</sup>Or any other device. Windows 7 supports pen drives. Only when you try to load USB drivers from an USB pendrive things might get *interesting*.

Comment: Good Catch!  It is wroth pointing out that in theory the user COULD make a Windows 7 installation that supports USB 3.0.  Once the user did that Windows 7 could be installed the same way as Windows 8+  Windows 7 does not by default include the required drivers to do this, Microsoft after Intel indicate this change would take place, made a point   of **not** updating the Windows 7 installation media.

Comment: ASRock have your footnote covered: "If you don't have an optical disc drive and wish to install Windows 7 with a USB drive, please find another computer and follow the instructions below..." - the instructions are too long to include in a comment, and that situation wasn't in the question.